# using nginx as proxy for both php and nodejs

Tags: php, nginx

I am looking to use Nginx as a proxy for a Nodejs application in addition to serving PHP content via Nginx (using PHP5-FPM).  I was able to serve PHP initially when the proxy setup was not in place.  However, now when I am using the proxy, the PHP setup is no longer working.  Should I specify a different location under the server settings (in sites-available/default) for PHP or use a separate server in the default file.  I currently have the following setup in the default file:

```
 upstream test {
        server 0.0.0.0:3002;
        keepalive 500;
}


server {
        listen 81 default_server;  
        listen [::]:81 default_server; #remove?

        root /var/www/;             #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location ~ /PHPApp {    ##url will include PHPApp
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3002; 
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pilot error - I was able to use the upstream option for multiple back end servers (e.g. NodeJS, Python etc.) and used multiple server directives to point to those back end servers.  I used the original server directive for PHP and was able to route traffic to the PHP, NodeJS and Python backends.

For instance:

```
upstream node {
        server 0.0.0.0:3002; ##varnish -> back end app server
        keepalive 500;
}

upstream python {
        server 0.0.0.0:8080;
        keepalive 500;
}


server {
        listen 81 default_server;  ## haproxy is using port 80 - nginx switched to 81
        listen [::]:81 default_server; #ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/;  #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://node;
        }

}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
server {
        listen 82;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}


server {
        listen 83;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name python;

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://python;
        }
}
```